# Scalar function in LinqToSql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, scalar

In ADO.Net/SQLClient I would often do something like this:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeKey = 1234`

...and fire it using executescalar to return the value of count - for a simple check if something exists.

How would I do the same using LinqToSql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (context.SomeTable.Any(row => row.SomeKey == 1234))
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

You could also use `Count()`.

```
if (context.SomeTable.Count(row => row.SomeKey == 1234) > 0)
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

But this requires always to go through all rows while `Any()` can return after the first matching row - so `Any()` might have better performance.

Comment: Fixed ^^ (Noise to get at least 15 characters... ^^)

Comment: You need a double equals to do a comparison `==`

Comment: C&P from the Question ... fixed ... still more bugs? :D

Answer (score 3):

Remember, Linq to Sql is deferred execution, which means, the query only actually executes when you access the collection. Therefore:

```
var q = (from p in db.SomeTable
        where p.SomeKey == 1234
        select p).Count();
```

Will turn into a SELECT Count() on the SQL side of things.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to see if something exists you can use the any function:

```
if (context.SomeTable.Any(i => i.SomeKey == 1234))
{
    return true;
}
```

or if you actually want to know that count you can use the where function and the count function:

```
context.SomeTable.Where(i=> i.SomeKey == 1234).Count();
```

Comment: You can move the predicate from Where() to Count() and save some typing.